# Animated Scatter Plot (Plotly, Python) - add custom title per frame

Tags: python, animation, plotly, scatter-plot

I have successfully created an animated scatter plot using plotly, and now I want to replace the title in each frame of the animation with custom text.

I referred to the solution in this chat in order to try achieve this:
https://community.plotly.com/t/dynamic-animation-title-annotation/38747/3

The input data is:

```
print(titles.to_dict())
```

{'Year': {0: 2021, 1: 2022, 2: 2023}, 'Text': {0: 'Title 1', 1: 'Title 2', 2: 'Title 3'}}

```
print(tagged_df.to_dict())
```

{'Unnamed: 0': {0: 1266, 1: 1289, 2: 1293, 3: 1304, 4: 1305, 5: 1311, 6: 1776, 7: 1790, 8: 1799}, 'LOCATION': {0: 'AUS', 1: 'AUT', 2: 'BEL', 3: 'BEL', 4: 'AUS', 5: 'AUT', 6: 'BEL', 7: 'AUT', 8: 'AUS'}, 'TIME': {0: 2021, 1: 2021, 2: 2021, 3: 2022, 4: 2022, 5: 2022, 6: 2023, 7: 2023, 8: 2023}, 'Value_rates': {0: 0.02833333, 1: -0.5487667, 2: -0.5487667, 3: 0.3415667, 4: 1.636667, 5: 0.3415667, 6: 1.350987085, 7: 1.350987085, 8: 3.580073801}, 'Value_cpi': {0: 2.86391, 1: 2.766667, 2: 2.440248, 3: 9.597511, 4: 6.594097, 5: 8.54687, 6: 2.345248207, 7: 2.382125997, 8: -100.0}, 'Region': {0: 'DM_Other', 1: 'DM_Europe', 2: 'DM_Europe', 3: 'DM_Europe', 4: 'DM_Other', 5: 'DM_Europe', 6: 'DM_Europe', 7: 'DM_Europe', 8: 'DM_Other'}, 'COUNTRY_NAME': {0: 'Australia', 1: 'Austria', 2: 'Belgium', 3: 'Belgium', 4: 'Australia', 5: 'Austria', 6: 'Belgium', 7: 'Austria', 8: 'Australia'}, 'COLOUR_tag': {0: 'purple', 1: 'pink', 2: 'pink', 3: 'pink', 4: 'purple', 5: 'pink', 6: 'pink', 7: 'pink', 8: 'purple'}, 'SIZE_tag': {0: 50, 1: 50, 2: 50, 3: 50, 4: 50, 5: 50, 6: 50, 7: 50, 8: 50}}

My code follows.
The chart looks fine, but the Title is not updating for each frame. How can I fix this?

```
#Import Libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly.express as px

# Create the scatter plot
fig = px.scatter(tagged_df, x="Value_cpi", y="Value_rates", 
                 animation_frame="TIME", 
                 animation_group="LOCATION",
                 color="COLOUR_tag", 
                 hover_name="COUNTRY_NAME",
                 size=tagged_df['SIZE_tag'].astype(float),  # Convert SIZE_tag to numeric
                 log_x=False, 
                 range_x=[-5, 90], range_y=[-5, 50],
                 title='This Title needs to be replaced',
                 labels={'Value_cpi': 'Inflation Rate', 'Value_rates': 'Nominal Interest Rate (3m T-Bill)'},
                 width=960, height=540,
                 template='plotly_dark',
                 size_max=50,  # Set the maximum dot size
            )

# Iterate through the buttons to set 'redraw': True
for button in fig.layout.updatemenus[0].buttons:
    button['args'][1]['frame']['redraw'] = True

# Update titles for each animation frame
for k in range(len(fig.frames)):
    matching_rows = tagged_df[tagged_df["TIME"].astype(int) == int(fig.frames[k].name)]
    if not matching_rows.empty:
        chart_title = titles[titles['Year'] == int(fig.frames[k].name)]['Text'].values[0]
        fig.frames[k]['layout'].update(title_text=chart_title)

fig.update_traces(
    marker=dict(opacity=0.7), 
    selector=dict(mode='markers')       # Ensure only markers are affected by the update
)

fig.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this part `titles[titles['Year'] == int(fig.frames[k].name)]['Text'].values[0]` of your code is returning the same value for each frame, so the chart title is not changing. If you want to change the title over the year with each frames, you can do it this way:

```
# Update titles for each animation frame
for k in range(len(fig.frames)):
    matching_rows = tagged_df[tagged_df["TIME"].astype(int) == int(fig.frames[k].name)]
    if not matching_rows.empty:
        custom_title = matching_rows['TIME'].values[0]
        fig.frames[k]['layout'].update(title_text='Year :'+str(custom_title))
```

Comment: I discovered that my original code does change the title, but only when I press "Play" - not when I use the slider. Also the play is pretty fast so it was easy for me to miss the titles as they update.

Comment: it was an assumption. I was unable to reproduce your code with the `titles` iist/dictionary you are using

Comment: I am sorry. I am still getting used to producing minimum reproducible examples.
Please let me know how I should adapt the example I have given. 

I assume I should I re-write my code so that it reads from the list/dictionary rather than the csv I am working from on my side.

Comment: it's fine as of now, just add the titles list

Comment: This is the titles list:
{'Year': {0: 2021, 1: 2022, 2: 2023}, 'Text': {0: 'Title 1', 1: 'Title 2', 2: 'Title 3'}}
I simplified it for the example

Answer (score 0):

I found a satisfactory solution which also allows me to change parameters such as the play speed, Title size, Title location, slider length, etc.

```
# Create the scatter plot
fig = px.scatter(tagged_df, x="Value_cpi", y="Value_rates", 
                 animation_frame="TIME", 
                 animation_group="LOCATION",
                 color="COLOUR_tag", 
                 hover_name="COUNTRY_NAME",
                 size=tagged_df['SIZE_tag'].astype(float),
                 log_x=False, 
                 range_x=[-10, 90], range_y=[-10, 50],
                 labels={'Value_cpi': 'Inflation Rate', 'Value_rates': 'Nominal Interest Rate (3m T-Bill)'},
                 width=800, height=500,
                 template='plotly_dark',
                 size_max=50,
            )

# Convert 'Year_Text' to integer
titles['Year'] = titles['Year'].astype(int)

# Create a dictionary to map years to titles
year_to_title = dict(zip(titles['Year'], titles['Text']))

# Iterate through the frames to update layout with annotations
for k in range(len(fig.frames)):
    frame_time = int(fig.frames[k].name)
    annotation_text = year_to_title.get(frame_time, "")  # Get title from the dictionary
    
    if annotation_text:
        fig.frames[k].layout.update(
            annotations=[
                dict(
                    x=0, y=1.15,  # Position at the top center
                    xref='paper', yref='paper',  # Use paper coordinates
                    text=annotation_text,
                    showarrow=False,  # Hide arrow
                    font=dict(size=32, color="white"),  # Customize font size and color
                )
            ]
        )

fig.update_traces(
    marker=dict(opacity=0.7), 
    selector=dict(mode='markers')
)

fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        dict(type='buttons',
             showactive=False,
             buttons=[
                 dict(label='Play',
                      method='animate',
                      args=[None, dict(frame=dict(duration=3000, redraw=True), fromcurrent=True, transition=dict(duration=0))]
                     ),
                 dict(label='Pause',
                      method='animate',
                      args=[[None], dict(frame=dict(duration=0, redraw=False), mode='immediate', transition=dict(duration=0))]
                     )
             ]
            )
        ],
    sliders=[dict(steps=[dict(args=[[f.name], dict(mode='immediate', redraw=True)],
                              label=str(f.name),
                              method='animate') for f in fig.frames],
                transition=dict(duration=0),
                x=0.1,  # Slider starting position
                len=1.0  # Slider length
               )
            ],
    title=''  # Set initial title
)

fig.show()
```